# Bash shell getting only PID from PS doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu and bash shell.

I can't understand why the following command returns the whole line instead of only `PID`s:

```
$ ps -ef | awk  "{print $2}" | head -3
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 feb18 ?        00:00:32 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 feb18 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww: I think the question can count as a programming question. It's about a single statement, which could as well be part of a script. Asking questions about the workings of a programming statement is, IMHO, covered by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a shell quoting issue. If in double quotes, the shell expands the "$2" to an empty string because it is unset. That leaves `awk '{print }'` which will print the whole line.

Use single quotes to prevent expansion:

```
ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | head -3
```

Btw, you can use the `ps` command to get the pid, `awk` isn't required for that:

```
ps -efho pid
```